# Adding credit card to google pay/ apple pay

Tags: flutter, credit-card, applepay, google-pay

I'm going to integrate my flutter application with GooglePay and ApplePay. However, I cannot find the guide or any plugin to add credit card from my application to Google Wallet/ Apple Wallet. Is there are any reference for me? many thanks.

I only can find adding the pass/loyalty card to the wallet, but it's not credit card or make payment with GooglePay/ ApplePay

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You need to ask for access to the push provisioning APIs: https://developers.google.com/pay/issuers/apis/push-provisioning/android

Comment: Did anyone finds any plugin for adding debit/credit cards to Apple/Samsung/Google wallets from Flutter application.